# How do I pass a random value from one function to another function using classes in C++?

Tags: c++, class

I have a sample of code for some framework that I am using. For ease of reading I have separated blocks of code from different files.

Tile.h

```
class Tile
{
public:
    Tile(int row, int column);
    ~Tile();

    void Draw();
    void Update(double delta);

    void SetValue(int value);
    int GetValue();

private:
    //Member variables
    Label* m_ValueLabel;
    int m_Value = 0;
    int m_Row;
    int m_Column;
    float duration = 0.0f;
    float xScale = 0;
    float yScale = 0;
};
```

Tile.cpp

```
void Tile::SetValue(int value)
{
    //Set the Tile's value
    m_Value = value;

    //if (m_Value != EMPTY_TILE)
    {
        //Update the Tile's Label
        m_ValueLabel->SetText(to_string(m_Value));
    }
    /*else
    {
        m_ValueLabel->SetText("");
    }*/
}
```

Game.h

```
class Game
{
public:
    Game();  //Constructor
    ~Game(); //Destructor

    void Update(double delta);
    void Draw();

    void HandleLeftMouseClick(float mouseX, float mouseY);
    void HandleRightMouseClick(float mouseX, float mouseY);
    void HandleKeyPress(Keyboard::Key key);

    bool isBoardFull();
    int GetEmptyTileIndex();

    void SpawnTile();

    void RandomizeSeed();
    int RandomRange(int min, int max);

private:
    //Member variables should go here
    Tile* m_Tiles[NUM_TILES];
    bool isTileFull[16] = {};
    int TileValueArray[5] = { 2,2,2,4,4 };
};
```

Game.cpp

```
void Game::SpawnTile()
{
    RandomizeSeed();
    int meaningfulVariableName = GetEmptyTileIndex();
    if (meaningfulVariableName != -1)
    {
            int RandomNumber = RandomRange(0,4);
            int TileValue = TileValueArray[RandomNumber];

    }
    else if (meaningfulVariableName == -1)
    {
        //Does nothing
    }
}
```

What I need to do with this is make it so that the TileValue created in Game.cpp can be passed to the SetValue function in Tile.cpp because the value created is required for m_Value in SetValue.

The majority of code present can probably be ignored, and anything commented out should not effect how I need the code to function at the moment. There is nothing wrong with the framework outside of these files, as I have used it several times before.

I know there are easier ways to do this, but this is how I am required to do it. I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this because anything that I have found online has not helped. If you think that you may need more code for clarification on something, please do not hesitate to ask. Also, in case it helps I am using this to create a 2048 clone.

Comment: Doesn't your `SpawnTile` function return a `Tile` object on which you can do a `newTile->SetValue(xx)`? It looks to me it doesn't do what its name says.

Comment: Several comments not stictly connected to question: `HandleLeftClick` and other handles should return either `bool` or smple enum to inform if they have successfully processed given input. `RandomizeSeed` doesn't sound like it should be visible from outside `Game` class, so moving to private part (or at least protected) is advised. This also holds true for `RandomRange()` which looks like internal heler function. Also as mentioned above, you `SpawnTile` should return either created `Tile` object, or pointer to that `Tile`, `void` in this case is counter-intuitive.

Comment: Well, **which tile** do you want to set the value of?

Answer (score -1):

You have a function `Game::GetEmptyTileIndex` which will return an index. You can use that index to set `Game::m_Tiles` by changing the `Game::SpawnTile` function like so:

```
// Game.cpp
void Game::SpawnTile()
{
    RandomizeSeed();

    // Returns a tile index.
    int meaningfulVariableName = GetEmptyTileIndex();

    if (meaningfulVariableName != -1)
    {
            int RandomNumber = RandomRange(0,4);
            int TileValue = TileValueArray[RandomNumber];
            // Set the value for the tile at the required index.
            m_Tiles[meaningfulVariableName]->SetValue(TileValue);
    }
    else if (meaningfulVariableName == -1)
    {
        //Does nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it gave me a compiler error that says "left of '.SetValue' must have class/struct/union"

Comment: Deference the pointer, see edits, or declare `Tile* m_Tiles[NUM_TILES]` without being a pointer.

Comment: Downvoted because there's no explanation of why they should do this.

Comment: He should do it because it passes the value to another `class` through `SetValue`. Could you elaborate as to how this does not answer the poster's question? The poster even left a question stating they used my answer and tried it out.